# Is it legal to receive a visitor who must quarantine?

Tags: covid-19, austria, quarantine

I live in Austria and I have a friend who is a UK citizen. He has to come to Austria and has to quarantine (he isn't fully vaccinated). He will quarantine at an apartment I rent (it's completely empty no one else lives there for now). Can I meet him at the bus station and direct him to my apartment or better even come with him to the apartment?

Comment: Are you sure your friend can even come at all? At the moment travel from the UK to Austria is not permitted, unless your friend meets one of the exceptions...

Comment: hes coming from his home country which is not in the list, but he still has to quarentine because he isnt fully vaccinated.

Comment: AFAIK you are not supposed to receive private visitors while in quarantine, and you are supposed to minimise contact with other people while travelling to the quarantine location. 
However it also appears that Austria does consider people "vaccinated" if they have only received the first dose, and that for 90 days.

Comment: "Legal" questions are a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com/. Answering this will require locating and carefully analyzing the most recent regulations in Austria, which people on law stack exchange are much better suited for (and more likely to actually do !)

Comment: Ignoring the legal aspect for a moment: the objective of the quarantine is to prevent infection of locals, including yourself, in case your friend is infected. So *any* contact should be avoided during the quarantine period.

Comment: This is a question you should ask your local Gesundheitsamt, who will probably know that your friend is starting a quarantine at that apartment. You are basically assisting your friend to swiftly arrive to the apartment after arriving by bus where the friend was near other passengers. They will probably advise you **not** to enter the apartment, but while maintaining social distance, accompanying them to the apartment will not be a problem.

Comment: @nohillside legal aspects aside, I think we can all agree that home-based quarantines were security theater since the very beginning (not to be confused with hotel based quarantines, where armed men escort you from the gate to your room). But of course the law is the law, no matter how much we don't like it.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, we can‘t agree, but this definitively takes the discussion into off-topic territory.

Comment: Note: what you mean with "visit" is not really a visit, is just a check-in procedure (required for his quarantine)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.